# How to force Java to use IPv4 instead IPv6?

Tags: windows, java, ipv6, ipv4

My Java browser plug-in is no longer working. When I open a page that has a Java element, Java cannot connect to the server.

After investigation, I found that Java was trying to use IPv6, while my network does not support IPv6, so Java always fails to connect.

I tried looking on Google and found that I should run Java with `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`, but how can I pass this to the browser?

I use Google Chrome and Java 7 update 5.

Comment: Why don't you disable the IPv6 protocol so Java won't have this option.

Comment: it is a old story, I do not know if I've disable IPv6 protocol, seems to have, I've forgotten, what I remember is I remove Java 7 and replace it with Java 6

Comment: Disabling is easy : [see this](http://www.informationweek.com/byte/personal-tech/desktop-operating-systems/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-windows-7/231400022).

Comment: @harrymc always copy content: that link is dead.

Comment: @javadba: Links are never dead : [see the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130916222122/http://www.informationweek.com/byte/personal-tech/desktop-operating-systems/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-windows-7/231400022), but it's outdated. Better google "Disable IPv6 On Windows" for half a million results.

Comment: It does not get passed the the browser it is used when the app starts.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**Put the options in `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable.** How to do this is already described in various other posts – although they usually talk about setting `PATH`, but it's all the same.

For example, on Linux, put the following in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

Comment: ok, thanks for your reply, although i use windows but your solution inspire me, thanks

Comment: See for example this post for setting environment variables: http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: Why does Java 'prefer' IPV6?  It seems to break code that was working.

Comment: How to set it in Windows ?

Comment: @Ribo: By default, Java uses dual-stack IPv6 when possible, that is, it uses IPv6 sockets that also support IPv4 addresses. These sockets are still compatible with IPv4 applications by using IPv4-mapped addresses. Therefore, this is a backward-compatible behavior.

Comment: IPv4-mapped addresses break proxies.

Answer (score 0):

when launching from the command line, add parameter:

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

ie:

java -jar -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true some.jar

Comment: The environment variable mentioned in the other answer will also work, though, and is recommended over environments where the java cmd isn't directly accessible